# Connect root domain name to dyndns?

Tags: domain-name-system, url-routing, dyndns

Is there any way to connect the **root** of a domain name to a dyndns account? [This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/6356/how-can-i-forward-all-requests-from-my-godaddy-domain-name-to-my-dyndns-entry) reveals how to get www.whatever.com to point to dyndns, but is there a way to get whatever.com itself to point to it?

The domain is registered with GoDaddy if that matters.

Comment: "root" is not the proper word (in the DNS, it means the root of all domains, where TLD like .COM or .FR are delegated). "apex" is the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible if you delegate complete control of the domain name to a compatible dynamic DNS provider.

The reason for this is that (as you've found) it's not possible to `CNAME` the apex of your domain to point at a third party dynamic service, because you have to have `NS` records and `SOA` records there too, and they can't co-exist with a `CNAME`.

Hence what you'd need is a DNS provider who will not only host the dynamic entry, but also host the `NS` and `SOA` records too.

Answer (score 0):

Some dynamic DNS services (such as the one I run, [DtDNS](http://www.dtdns.com/)), allow you to link the A record for the base domain to the dynamic IP address, just like you would with a hostname provided by the DNS service.  I believe DynDNS.com allows this, as do some other DNS providers.

If you're hosting your DNS with a static DNS provider like GoDaddy, you will not be able to use a CNAME record on the base domain to link it up with a dynamic hostname elsewhere like you can with hostsnames like 'www' (as you mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

DynDNS offers a pro account that does this. We use it and its fantastic (just like their other services).

Highly recommend.